# lotus.domino.Stream locks files even after close()

Tags: java, eclipse, stream, lotus-notes

Hello Domino programmers!

I work on a Java application using Notes classes.

I wanted to use lotus.domino.Session object in order to create stream. I wanted to stream local computer files in order to embed them in a MIME field.

However, though created stream is finally closed, I can't delete source of attached file. It looks like Notes is not closing stream correctly.

Issue occurs even when I just open and close a stream, f.e.

```
Stream stream = session.createStream();
stream.open(attachmentPath);
stream.close();
stream.recycle();
// MORE CODE
```

Document is locked till the end of main function.

I have no idea what could be causing it, but in result it leaves some temp files, which can't be deleted through code.

What could be cause of this issue?

Any help will be appreciated!
// I use 9.0 designer and 9.0 development server.

Comment: This was reported previously, and an answer was accepted - but it's unclear to me if it was ever really resolved.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516858/extracting-attachments-from-lotus-notes-api-using-embeddedobject-creating-eotm

Answer (score 0):

Move the stream.recycle(); statement to the end of the function in which it is being used.  I was having the same issue until I moved it to the end, just before the last '}' of that same function.  Worked for me.